# How to add percentage in Sankey chart?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization, sankey-diagram

I would like to create a sankey chart, based on a google sheets entry.
In the google sheet, you will find a column with the source, another one with the destination and the third column shows the value.

Thats a screenshot of the Spreadsheet:
[image]

I wrote a script to create a sankey diagram showing the dependicies from source to destination.

In the sankey diagram, you several nodes (a coloized bar). The script for the sankey diagram are shown here:

code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .createMenu('Zusatzfunktionen')
        .addItem('SankeyDiagram', 'openDialog')
        .addToUi();
}

function getSpreadsheetData() {
    // ID of your Document, take from URL
    var ssID = "",
        // which Sheet? [0] is the first and so on...
        sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0],
        data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    return data;
}

function openDialog() {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
        .setHeight(300)
        .setWidth(1000);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
        .showModalDialog(html, 'Sankey Diagram');
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <base target="_top">
      <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="main"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         google.load('visualization', '1', {
           packages: ['corechart', 'sankey']
         });      google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
           
           function initialize() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getSpreadsheetData();
           }
           
           function drawChart(rows) {
             console.log(rows);
             var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows);
             var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('main'));
             chart.draw(data, {width: 900, sankey: {iterations: 64}});
           }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here you can find a screenshot of the sankey diagramm, created by the script shown above.

[image]

In the second step, i would like to add additional information at each node in the sankey diagram. My goal is to add the percentage of each each node. The picture shows my favored solution.

[image]

How can i modify my script to calculate the percentage share of each node related to the total value of column 3 in the spreadsheet?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Pre and Post version`. Are "Pre" and "Post" the sample input and output situations you expect, respectively?

Comment: PRE is the current version/visualization including nodes and streams. The post version is the favored one with a percentage share of each node.